# What's the macro doing in MASM32?

Tags: syntax, masm32

```
  szText MACRO Name, Text:VARARG
    LOCAL lbl
      jmp lbl
        Name db Text,0
      lbl:
    ENDM
```

Anyone knows what this macro's doing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it creates a zero-terminated string (hence, sz). The symbol for the string is whatever you pass as the Name parameter to the macro, and it contains whatever you pass as the Text parameter, plus a terminating 0.

It outputs a jump instruction to jump past the string, followed by the bytes of the string itself. The label for the jump is declared to be local to the macro, so it doesn't pollute the global namespace.

It's been a while since I've done x86 assembly language, but I guess this would put the string data right in the code segment, rather than putting it in a data segment, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: But it seems `Name db Text,0` is never run since it's always jumped away,right?

Comment: It's just data. It doesn't need to be 'run'. In fact, it can't be run. The assembler sees it in the source code and includes the bytes in the obj file, and includes the symbol in the obj file.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate how can `Name db Text,0` take affect when it's never run?

Comment: The assembler reads the entire assembly language source file from beginning to end. It generates code and data as output into an object file. That object file would include a symbol for `Name`, and the data. Only when the object file is linked into an executable and that executable is run would the `jmp` instruction be performed that would cause *execution* to skip over those bytes. But during *compilation*, the `jmp` instruction just causes the assembler to output a `jmp` opcode. The assembler keeps going straight on through the source code. Make sense?